# Angular unit test case for responsive mobile button

Tags: angular, angular-material

For my header component based on the screen resolution I have left hamburger menu and right hamburger icon. For the test case i need to write whether the menu is clickable or not.

For the reference I have two button `a` and `b`.

1) My question is based on the screen size do i need to write the test case?

2) Following test case which is correct or not?

`it('should call onClick method', () => {
  const onClickMock = spyOn(component, 'onClick');
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
  expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more an E2E test than a unit test. In unit tests you should just test the methods, not the UI or visibility of buttons.
And with E2E tests you test the UI. If needed also in different screen-resolutions to check the visibility on different devices/screens.

Comment: I have MatMenu, how to write the test case for MatMenu is open?

Comment: Just try [Angular E2E](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-e2e-testing-with-the-angular-cli-and-protractor).
And in the Unit-Tests you can test your methods functionality (given input compared with expected output)